# working with angular js and lumen

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, lumen

I have put AngularJS app files inside `public/app` folder in lumen.
I have `index.php` in `resources/view` folder which will be starting application point for frontend. And running lumen as

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public.
```

When I hit `localhost:8000` from my browser, it should load my AngularJS/html frontend showing UI part. It's not working as expected.

Is it an issue with loading those JS files (`public/app` folder) in `index.html` file? Is there any standard way to integrate and execute AngularJS and lumen altogether?

Comment: How did you put the javascript in the index.html? You'll call the view render on the controller normally and the angularJs will be executed. Please post your code, this way we can help better.